# javascript - array displaying two different arrays in logging

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, duplicates, artificial-intelligence

I'm extremely confused as to what is going on in my javascript code. I am trying to write a function that will create an array of random points. However, when I log the array inside the loop (whose function is to add points to the array), and then log it again outside of the loop, I get two different arrays printed.

The first, as predicted as the list of random X,Y points, but the second log only contains the last inputed X,Y point.

```
function Pick()
{
   var numPoints = 4 * Math.floor(4+Math.random()*5);
   var chosen_pts = [];
   var lastPt;
   for(var i = 0;i<numPoints;i++)
   {
       if(chosen_pts.length==0)
       {
           var temp = new Point(Math.floor(Math.random()*250),Math.floor(Math.random()*250));
           var newPt = pickClose(temp);
           chosen_pts.push(newPt);
           lastPt = newPt;
       }
       else{
          var newPt = pickClose(lastPt);
          chosen_pts.push(newPt); 
          }
        console.log(chosen_pts[i]); //LINE 106

   }
   console.log("\noutside of the loop:")
   for(var i = 0;i<numPoints;i++)
   {
      console.log(chosen_pts[i]);   //LINE 111
   }
}
```

See Photos of Console
[Console Array 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsZcP.png)
[Console Array 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWJrn.png)

edit:

```
function pickClose(lastPt)
{
        var x = lastPt["X"];
        var y = lastPt["Y"];
        var dx = 0;
        var dy = 0;
        var rand = Math.floor(1+Math.random()*100);

        if(rand<50){
            dx = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            dy = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
            if( (dx+dy)%3==0 ){
                dx*=-1;
            }
        }
        else if(rand<80)
        {
            dx = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
            dy = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
            if( (dx+dy)%3==0 ){
                dy*=-1;

            }
        }
        else{
            dx = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*60);
            dy = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*60);
            if( (dx+dy)%4==0 ){
                dx*=-1;
                dy*=-1;

            }
        }
        if( (x+dx) < 500&& (x+dx) >=0 )
            lastPt["X"]+=dx;
        else
            lastPt["X"]-=dx;


        if( (y+dy) < 500&& (y+dy) >=0 )
            lastPt["Y"]+=dy;
        else
            lastPt["Y"]-=dy;

        return lastPt;

  }
```

looks pretty messy, but essentially I wanted a different range of values to randomly choose from for(dx,dy) based on an initial random number.

Comment: The `pickClose` function seems to be the culprit. Include it's source code please.

Comment: I don't think it's the issue considering the first time the `console.log` is called it prints out different numbers for each point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pickClose` function always returns the passed element. Object in javascript are passed *by reference*, so any changes you do to the object later will also apply to all other references to the object you have stored.

To clarify:

```
var point1 = new Point(1, 2);
var point2 = pickClose(point1);
// inside pickClose, parameter lastPt = point1:
  lastPt["X"] += dx; // <- this also alters point1!
  lastPt["Y"] += dy; // <- this also alters point1!
```

So if you want to return a *new* `Point` inside your function (and not change the passed one), you have to create a new object that you alter and return:

```
var newX = x, newY = y;
// instead of:
lastPt["X"]+=dx;
// do:
newX += dx;

// then, at the bottom, instead of
return lastPt;
// create a new instance
return new Point(newX, newY);
```

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith no problem! if the answer solves your question please mark it as accepted, so it does not show up as "waiting for answer".

Answer (score 0):

Your pickClose function takes lastPt as a reference, so you are modifying the Point that already is in the array and adding it again.

try changing your line 103 to:

```
var newPt = pickClose(new Point(lastPt.X, lastPt.Y));
```